# Add a line to the subplot I specified in R

Tags: r, plot

I have already created 4 plots

```
x1 <- rnorm(10)
x2 <- rnorm(10)
x3 <- rnorm(10)
x4 <- rnorm(10)

par(mfrow=c(2,2))
 plot(x1,t="p",main = "1")
 plot(x2,t="p",main = "2")
 plot(x3,t="p",main = "3")
 plot(x4,t="p",main = "4")
```

[image]

I want to add a line to the first plot..
I can add a line at the initial stage of running the code

```
x1 <- rnorm(10)
x2 <- rnorm(10)
x3 <- rnorm(10)
x4 <- rnorm(10)

par(mfrow=c(2,2))
 plot(x1,t="p",main = "1") ; lines(rnorm(10),col=2)
 plot(x2,t="p",main = "2")
 plot(x3,t="p",main = "3")
 plot(x4,t="p",main = "4")
```

[image]

But the question is : how to add a line to the first plot after all four plots already exist, like in first picture

```
x1 <- rnorm(10)
x2 <- rnorm(10)
x3 <- rnorm(10)
x4 <- rnorm(10)

par(mfrow=c(2,2))
 plot(x1,t="p",main = "1") 
 plot(x2,t="p",main = "2")
 plot(x3,t="p",main = "3")
 plot(x4,t="p",main = "4")

 
 # how to add line in first plot now ?
 lines(rnorm(10),col=2)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The graphical parameter `mfg`:

> A numerical vector of the form `c(i, j)` where `i` and `j` indicate which figure in an array of figures is to be drawn next (if setting) or is being drawn (if enquiring). The array must already have been set by `mfcol` or `mfrow`.

```r
par(mfrow = c(2, 2))
plot(x1, main = "1") 
plot(x2, main = "2")
plot(x3, main = "3")
plot(x4, main = "4")

par(mfg = c(1, 1))
lines(rnorm(10), col = 2)
```

[image]